# How can I project a data set into lower dimension space?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, dimensionality-reduction

I am new in dimensionality reduction. for iris dataset, with n=150 points, in 3 dimensional space (Sepal-length, Sepal-width,Petal-length) . how can i project them to 2d??

Comment: Principal components analysis would be a good starting point. Enjoy, this is a classic!

Answer (score 2):

Projection to a lower dimension (or same dimension) can be achieved by **matrix multiplication**. In your example, the original data matrix $X$ is $150 \times 3$ (in the definition of "data matrix", each row is one data point, and number of columns are number of features.). If we want to project all the data into 2D space, we will use a $3 \times 2$ matrix $P$. The result of $XP$ is $150 \times 2$ matrix.

Here is an example of using PCA to do dimension reduction. Please note how the projection matrix $P$ ($3 \times 2$) is defined.

```
> d=iris[,1:3]
> pr.out=prcomp(d, scale=T)

> # reduce to 2D
> P=pr.out$rotation[,1:2]

> P
                    PC1         PC2
Sepal.Length  0.6290662 -0.43339843
Sepal.Width  -0.3611443 -0.89806788
Petal.Length  0.6883680 -0.07509912

> head(as.matrix(scale(d)) %*% P)
           PC1        PC2
[1,] -1.850964 -0.4227153
[2,] -1.588617  0.7121722
[3,] -1.945261  0.4090196
[4,] -1.860383  0.6588919
[5,] -2.009789 -0.5764188
[6,] -1.837503 -1.4166620
```

---

We can check our manual projection $XP$ and PCA output. They are the same. (Comparing to the first two column / 2D of `pr.out$x`)

```
> head(pr.out$x)
           PC1        PC2         PC3
[1,] -1.850964 -0.4227153 -0.12939389
[2,] -1.588617  0.7121722 -0.26157290
[3,] -1.945261  0.4090196 -0.03136284
[4,] -1.860383  0.6588919  0.07069857
[5,] -2.009789 -0.5764188  0.00614575
[6,] -1.837503 -1.4166620 -0.01014686
```